# what version of Ionic will fit with my meteor 1.4.1.1 on Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit

Tags: angularjs, node.js, meteor, ionic-framework, ubuntu-12.04

I am working on Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit with nodejs 6.4.0, meteor 1.4.1.1 and angular. What version of ionic will fit with mine.

Thanks.